# How do I add page numbers to a SharePoint list instead of having the Item numbers

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem

How do I add page numbers to a SharePoint list instead of having the Item numbers at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Which page numbers? Can you elaborate a little deeper?

Comment: At the bottom of a full list SharePoint displays e.g 1-30 which refers to the items, i want this to be page numbers instead of item numbers @rafaelbonametti

Comment: So what defines a pagenumber? You mean 1-30 should be page #1 and 31-60 page #2 ? What should happen van you change the number of items displayed on one page? The current UI never did pagenumbers because it has no clue how many pages there are. So you need to add code and do calculations. The mentioned XSLT is oldskool (and XSLT is a pain), modern approach is Client-Side-Rendering and using REST to get all the required info.. also more future proof for the SharePoint Framework.. But all requires some serious scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two options:

1- You could use a Content Query WebPart with Pagination that Waldek put together first for SP2007 and later on for SP2010.

[Adding paging numbers to the control list with paging template](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part-paging/)

2- You can download Waldek's code and extend his webpart with new functionality. You could also just extend the CQWP out of the box and build your own paging. I wrote an article some time ago explaining how you could extend the CQWP and create your own XSLT functions... for instance to create the paging...

[Create your own xlst functions using c](http://www.helpmeonsharepoint.com/2012/05/create-your-own-xslt-functions-using-c.html)